# Phoenix Ecto - Variable in model method

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am using the Phoenix web framework (Elixir) to rewrite a python based API delivery service we have and am running into a small issue.

I am trying to create a basic model method where by when called you pass it a serial number, it queries the database via Ecto and returns the result. Looking through the documentation I should be able to use interpolation to define the variable in the query but I am still getting an error.

**lib/test_result.ex** file

```
defmodule Webservices.TestResult do
  use Ecto.Schema

      schema "test_result" do
            field :date_added, Ecto.DateTime
            field :serial, :string
            field :sequence_id, :integer
            field :last_completed_stage, :integer
            field :last_completed_sequence, :integer
            field :workorder, :string
            field :product, :string
            field :is_complete, :integer
            field :is_scrapped, :integer
            field :value_stream, :string
            field :promise_date, Ecto.Date
            field :fail_lock, :integer
            field :sequence_rev, :integer
            field :date_updated, Ecto.DateTime
            field :date, Ecto.Date
            field :time, Ecto.Time
            field :ptyp2, :string
            field :wo_qty, :integer
            field :is_active, :integer
            field :is_time_lock, :integer
            field :time_lock_timestamp, Ecto.DateTime
            field :scrap_reason, :string
            field :scrapped_by, :integer
      end
  end
```

**lib/test_result_detail.ex** file

```
defmodule Webservices.TestResultDetail do
  use Ecto.Schema, :model
  import Ecto.Query

  schema "test_result_detail" do
    field :status_id, :integer
    field :station_id, :integer
    field :stage_id, :integer
    field :operator_id, :integer
    field :failstep, :string
    field :shift, :integer
    field :sequence_rev, :integer
    field :date_added, Ecto.Date
    field :date_timestamp, Ecto.DateTime
    field :date_time, Ecto.Time
    field :stage_order, :integer
    field :serial_number, :string
    field :is_retest, :integer
    field :retest_reason, :string

    has_many :result_id, Webservices.TestResult
end


  def last_completed_test(serial) do
    from c in Webservices.TestResultDetail,
      join: t in TestResult, on: t.id == c.result_id,
      select: {t.serial, c.station_id, c.stage_id, c.operator_id, c.sequence_rev},
      where: t.serial == ^serial,
      order_by: [desc: c.id],
      limit: 1
  end

end
```

**My controller:**

```
defmodule Webservices.OPTController do
    use Webservices.Web, :controller

    alias Webservices.Router
    import Webservices.Router.Helpers

    def last(conn, %{"serial" => serial}) do
        import Ecto.Query

        results = Webservices.TestResultDetail.last_completed_test(serial)
        render(conn, "last.json", results: results)

    end
end
```

I am getting the following compile error:

> == Compilation error on file web/controllers/opt_controller.ex ==
>   ** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) variable `serial` is not a valid query expression. Variables need to be explicitly interpolated in queries
>   with ^
>       expanding macro: Ecto.Query.where/3
>       web/controllers/opt_controller.ex:12: Webservices.OPTController.index/2
>       (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.|>/2
>       web/controllers/opt_controller.ex:13: Webservices.OPTController.index/2
>       (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:117: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1

Comment: `where: c.serial == ^serial` -> `where: c.serial_number == ^serial`

Comment: Rather `t`. I created an answer.

Comment: c.serial is a FK link to another table where there is a serial field. The serial_number field is not used in the test_result_detail table, sorry for the confusion. I updated my question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You joined two tables and in your `t` table there's `:serial` field. In `c` there's `:serial_number`. Just apply this `where` clause on `t.serial == ^serial`.

Comment: That was a definite fat finger nice catch. I've updated but am still seeing the same error.

Comment: ugh, that was actually the issue along with one other typo I had in another file.